# Is there an event like BeforeFolderMove for copying folders?

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm looking for events in VBA Outlook, triggered when I copy a folder to another folder.

When I move the folder with a right mouse-click, I get the event BeforeFolderMove.

When I copy the folder, there is no event triggered.
Is there an event like BeforeFolderMove?

```vb
Private Sub myFolderSelected_BeforeFolderMove(ByVal MoveToFolder As Outlook.Folder, ByRef Cancel As Boolean) Handles myFolderSelected.BeforeFolderMove
```

If I move a folder in Outlook only with the mouse via drag and drop, there's no event fired like `BeforeFolderMove` fired in VBA I can react on.

Any events I can look for?

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the [Folders.FolderAdd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.folders.folderadd?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaol11.chm308);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) event which is fired when a folder is added to the specified `Folders` collection (copied and pasted).

```
Public WithEvents myOlFolders As Outlook.Folders  
 
Public Sub Initialize_handler()  
 Set myOlFolders = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders  
End Sub  
 
Private Sub myOlFolders_FolderAdd(ByVal Folder As Outlook.Folder)  
 Folder.Display  
End Sub
```